# Create a one column vector out of a data frame in r

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

What I'm looking for is to create a vector out of a data frame in r.
Basically what I have is a data frame with four columns (1 to 4) and four rows (A to D) and its values (a.1, a.2, etc.) like this:

```
     1    2    3    4
A   a.1  a.2 ...   
B   b.1
C
D
```

What I want is to create one vector with the row names A1, A2,..., B1,...D4 and its values like this, but I don't know how:

```
   value
A1 a.1
A2 a.2
B1 b.1
```

Comment: Take a look at the melt function from the reshape2 package: http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html

Comment: See `unstack(PlantGrowth) - > y` `stack(y)`

Answer (score 3):

Some variation on this, keeping with base R functions:

```
data.frame(value=unlist(df), row.names=outer(rownames(df), colnames(df), paste0))
#   value
#a1     a
#b1     b
#a2     b
#b2     c
```

Source data:

```
df <- data.frame(`1`=c("a","b"),`2`=c("b","c"),row.names=c("a","b"),check.names=FALSE)
#  1 2
#a a b
#b b c
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create an index column using your row names and then `melt` the data accordingly and then rename your row names according to your two new columns, something like

```
library(reshape2)
df$indx <- row.names(df)
res <- melt(df, "indx")
row.names(res) <- with(res, paste0(indx, variable))
res["value"]
#    value
# A1   a.1
# B1   b.1
# C1   c.1
# D1   d.1
# A2   a.2
# B2   b.2
# C2   c.2
# D2   d.2
# A3   a.3
# B3   b.3
# C3   c.3
# D3   d.3
# A4   a.4
# B4   b.4
# C4   c.4
# D4   d.4
```